# Excel 2013 Workbook Size Optimizer not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, powerpivot

I have a large PowerPivot/PowerView workbook that needs to be cleaned up. Microsoft offers a free tool called the [Workbook Size Optimizer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38793) for situations like this, but I have not been successful in getting it to work. Either I will click the button in the ribbon and nothing will happen. Or I will get an error:

```
 "The workbook cannot be optimized if there are unsaved changes. Save the file and try again."
```

I have saved the file over and over and run into the same issues. Has anyone successfully used the Workbook Size Optimizer or have any tips on getting this to work properly?